# How can I preview the CiviCRM contribution thank-you page

Tags: civicrm

I want to modify the HTML in the CiviCRM thank you page but I need to see how the page looks on the site before making it public. Is there a preview page or even a live link I can use?
Further is there a way to preview the automatic receipt e-mail.

Thanks

Comment: CiviCRM will be launching it's own Stack Exchange site at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/ soon.  It's in private beta state now.  If you use my Drupal.org contact form (https://www.drupal.org/user/48877/contact_, I'll send you an invite.  You are much more likely to get an answer to this type of question there since it really isn't specific to integrating Drupal with CiviCRM.